# What is the html code to show the registered symbol

Tags: html

Not `&reg;` that shows a registered symbol next to text, I want the small one that sits on the top right hand corner of text. What is the entity code for that?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There's none. Just use [`<sup>` (superscript)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup) to put it on "top right".

```
<p>StackOverflow<sup>&reg;</sup></p>
```

Which should show up as StackOverflow<sup>®</sup> instead of StackOverflow®.

Answer (score 7):

```
<sup>&reg;</sup>
```

The ® code itself is a "regular" character - use `<sup>` tags to superscript it and get that effect.  Or in CSS, apply the following style to the character:

```
vertical-align: super;
```

So there is no "preformatted" character like ™ which is already super-scripted and small.  You have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Or if you don't exactly *like* the way that `<sup>%reg;</sup>` renders, you can always customize it: something like

```
<span class="sup">&reg;</span>

.sup {
    font-size: 70%;
    vertical-align: super;
}
```

***note:** this is untested CSS*

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<sup>&reg;</sup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Hex value for Reg symbol code: `&#174;`